# RequireJS на вторичной загрузке скрипта возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Пытаюсь сделать такую вещь используя RequireJS:

1. Есть скрипт `Script1.js`, который выполняет какие-то действия с данными из скрипта `DB.js`.
2. Есть скрипт `Script2.js`, который так же выполняет какие-то действия с данными из скрипта `DB` и подгружается этот скрипт из `script1.js`.
3. Есть сам скрипт `DB`, который просто имеет переменные с необходимыми данными.

Примерный кусок кода:

```js
//Script1.js
define(["DB", "Script2"], function (DB, Script2) {
 return function Script1() {
  console.log(DB); //выводит function () { }, всё круто
  this.script2 = new Script2();
 }
);

//Script2.js
define(["DB"], function (DB) {
 return function Script2(cid) {
  console.log(DB); //выводит undefined, не то, что хотелось бы
 }
});

//DB.js
define(function () {
 //сюда код попадает единственный раз, когда RequireJS подключает его из Script1.js
 var DB = function () {};
 DB.someData = { one: "two" };
 return DB;
});
```

В `Script2.js` в переменную `DB` почему-то приходит `undefined`. Т.е. типа файл `DB` уже подгружался однажды, и *RequireJS* решил просто ничего не делать и не возвращать. Я уверен, что он знает, что делает, но хочется узнать как всё таки получить то, что я у него прошу?

`DB` - это такое некое подобие "класса" со статическими свойствами. В данной реализации пока пытался решить проблему я понял, что-то, что сейчас написано если бы и работало как я думал, то каждый раз возвращалась бы новая функция-конструктор `DB`, а хотелось бы ссылку на созданную в начале.

В общем, пытался объяснить как мог.

Итог: приходит `undefined`, хотя я ожидал функцию-конструктор `DB`. Если вы помочь хотите, но проблемы не поняли, я попытаюсь объяснить подробнее.

Comment: Что-то в духе define(["Script2"]) и var DB = require("DB"), он в Script1, он загрузился потому что зависим от Script2 и его можно звать синхронно. Проблему понял, она возникает часто, requirejs действительно знает что делает, пишу комментарием потому что давно с requirejs не работал, там кажется еще есть какой-то нюанс, а щас проверять неохота)

Comment: Но вообще я что-то глазом с ходу не вижу чтобы этот код не работал, обычно такое происходит если кольцевая зависимость, а если много одинаковых хвостов, кажется должно работать.

Comment: Ну плюс бывает что забываешь вернуть что-то из модуля, криво его задефайнишь define('smth', ...) вместо define (['smth') и такого же рода опечатки.

Comment: Попробуй сделать [mcve] например тут в сниппете, либо на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть что на самом деле происходит

Answer (score 0):

С подсказкой от **Утка Учится Уму** понял, что проблема была в циклической зависимости. Пример не до конца моделировал реальную ситуацию в проекте. Как и сказал **Grundy**, нужен был воспроизводимый пример, тогда было бы проще понять.
В общем решение из документации: когда приходит undefined при циклической зависимости, я напрямую этому свойству присваиваю следующее:

```
DB = require("data/db/DB");
```

Наверное есть решение по лучше (как минимум избавиться от циклической зависимости), но пока в процессе обучения не стал сильно углубляться, пытаюсь не запутаться в куче новой информации, так что такое решение пока вполне подходит.